# How to use a Future in a non-Future class

Tags: function, flutter, dart, future

I’m a newbie at Flutter. I’m trying to parse a local json file (a List of Maps) to use in other parts of the application.

Since it’s a json parsing, it requires a Future function (**getJson()**, in the example below). This function is parsing correctly, as the ‘print’ in line 26 shows.

**I/flutter ( 6478): Line 26 [{firstName: John, id: 937206439937}, {firstName: Claudia, id: 8473759437373}, {firstName: Marie-Louise, id: 97745400283}]**

I need to use this result in **‘class _MyHomePageState extends State‘**, which is not a Future. I call the Future in line 41,

**var myList = decupagemJson();**

but when I try to print the value (just for checking if it returned correctly), I get **‘Instance of ‘Future'** instead of the value the Future should return.

**I/flutter ( 6478): Line 41 Instance of 'Future'**

[Results from prints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQUpn.png)

I have searched for a solution for weeks, but none of them could solve this.
How can I calculate a value in a Future function, and then use this value in other classes which are not Future? All answers I’ve seen up to now refer to calling the Future in another Future, but I need to call for the result of a Future inside **‘class _MyHomePageState extends State‘**.

What can I do?

Thank you very much for your help.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

Future <dynamic> decupagemJson() async {
  var resposta = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/myData.json');
  List dadosExtraidos = json.decode(resposta);

  print('Line 26 $dadosExtraidos'); //just to check if parsing was completed

  return dadosExtraidos;
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var myList = decupagemJson();
    print('Line 41 $myList'); //to check if value returned from Future is correct

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(''),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- it's a bad pratice to make future call inside the build like that
- use futureBuilder instead of that, it will be more effcient

Comment: I don't know about "efficient", but this is pretty much the only right answer here.  initState and dispose should *not* be async (nor can build).  initState can *set up* a Future that can be watched in build, but otherwise, the object needs to be completely configured before build begins.

Comment: futureBuilder is what you need 
to wait until you get the result  until that you can show empty widget with SizedBox.shrinl()

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dali. 
You confirmed a suspicius I had. Future marries Future only. I started with one approach and then the routine using the Future data got stuck in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "then" like this:

```
decupagemJson().then((value){
    print('Line 41 $value');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Client.
Didn't think of using 'then' because not used to it yet. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "then", but no before your statement return, and yes inside initState:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // USE THIS
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    decupagemJson().then((value){
      // here you put the desired return, using the VALUE variable, for exemple:
      // myList = value;
    });
  }
  // UNTIL HERE

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(''),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Luís. I never used 'then' and will experiment with it.

Answer (score 0):

The way in which you are getting data from local JSON is not correct. because you need a model class to get access to the instance of the class. follow the following steps you will get your answer.

**1:**Create a model class.

```
class UserModel {
  final id;
  final firstName;

  UserModel({
    this.firstName,
    this.id,
  });

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserModel(
      id: json['id'],
      firstName: json['firstName'],
    );
  }
}
```

**2:**Return List of map data from your Given Future function the return type must be List of UserModel.

```
Future<List<UserModel>?> decupagemJson() async {
  var resposta = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/myData.json');
  List dadosExtraidos = json.decode(resposta);
  return dadosExtraidos.map((user) => UserModel.fromJson(user)).toList();
}
```

**3:**Use **FutureBuilder** to get data from **decupagemJson()** function And use **ListView.Builder** inside **FutureBuilder** to access the Index of **List of mapped** data.
Note That the **FutureBuilder** type must be the same as the function, from where we returning the data.

```
 FutureBuilder<List<UserModel>?>(
          builder: (con, snap) {
            if (snap.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snap.data!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    height: 90,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text('id :${snap.data![index].id}'),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 3,
                        ),
                        Text('name :${snap.data![index].firstName}'),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
          future: myList,
        ),
```

**Here is the Complete Code just copy paste and Thanks me**

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserModel {
  final id;
  final firstName;

  UserModel({
    this.firstName,
    this.id,
  });

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserModel(
      id: json['id'],
      firstName: json['firstName'],
    );
  }
}

Future<List<UserModel>?> decupagemJson() async {
  var resposta = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/myData.json');
  List dadosExtraidos = json.decode(resposta);
  return dadosExtraidos.map((user) => UserModel.fromJson(user)).toList();
}

class YourClassName extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _YourClassNameState createState() => _YourClassNameState();
}

class _YourClassNameState extends State<YourClassName> {
  late Future<List<UserModel>?> myList;
  @override
  void initState() {
    myList = decupagemJson();
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //to check if value returned from Future is correct

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(''),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child:
        FutureBuilder<List<UserModel>?>(
          builder: (con, snap) {
            if (snap.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snap.data!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    height: 90,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text('id :${snap.data![index].id}'),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 3,
                        ),
                        Text('name :${snap.data![index].firstName}'),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
          future: myList,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Mehran.
You saved my day... and future projects.

Comment: if this answer helped you. then you have to mark it as the right answer to help others as well. Thank You!

Comment: @WagnerCorreaMunhe